# I have a problem when I want to use ''sudo apt update''

Tags: updates

```
az1@az1-HP-ZBook-15u-G5:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for az1: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for az1: 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Obviously a problem with an additional source added to your system. Remove the source and the update will work.

Comment: Seems like all the clues you need are in the output: The problem is related to your ProtonVPN source. Next step is for you to determine if you added ProtonVPN correctly or if you made a mistake...or if the ProtonVPN instructions are somehow erroneous.